# I cannot generate the object of class (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement this data structure:
  [The blue print I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/416GG.png)

I wrote the code shown in the picture:
[the model structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZpAE.png)
[The error code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afi4N.png)

Please help me out by explaining the wrong reason and how to fix it. Thank you so much and I appreciate it.

Comment: Please do not put picture of your code - paste your code, etc in your question. You can click 'edit' and make adjustments. See also here: [ask].

Comment: You can't access your property value at initiation time. Change your `PTCA_1`declaration to from `let` to `lazy var` or make it computed property `var PTCA_1 : Level_2 { return .init(whatever) }`

Comment: I tried, but the website rule is so rigorous that it always reject my code structure even though I tried tons of times. Please instruct me how to successfully post a snip of code. Thank you

Comment: 1) Add your code 2) select it 3) press command-k to format it properly

Comment: can you show me the code. I just learn, I cannot quickly get what you mean. Thank you

Comment: Note that it is Swift naming convention to name your var starting with a lowercase letter and use an uppercase letter instead of underscore .

Comment: I changed to: lazy var PTCA_1_tits = Level_3(titles: ["OM3", "OM4", "OS2", "View All"])     but does not work

Answer (score 0):

As the error states you cannot use one instance variable to initialize other one (as they are being initialized at the same time).

You can either make your `PTCA_1_tits` and `PTCA_2_tits` static (which would take it out of the `self` initialization) or make `PTCA_1` lazy - which means it will get initialized when it's needed for the first time. By that time `self` is already initialized.

Comment: I've changed to: lazy var PTCA_1_tits = Level_3(titles: ["OM3", "OM4", "OS2", "View All"])  but does not work

Comment: If you don't want to use other instance variables in your init you don't have to use `lazy`. What is the error now?

Comment: Thank you it works , I also have an other question that if I wrote the level 1 = (titles: [Level 2 Obj1..., ...]) , I still need to add lazy var right?

Comment: Correct, because you are using instance variable in `init` of some other variable.

Comment: Thank you so much. You help me a lot :-)

Comment: No worries, if you are happy with the answer please accept it :). Thanks